# need to insert this in a bat file

Tags: batch-file

This script auto generates the image tag, but i need to put this command into a windows bat file. This piece of code works fine when written in cmd window.

```
FOR %i IN (*.JPG) DO ECHO ^<img src="%i" /^> >> index.html
```

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In batch files you need to use %%variable format instead of %variable

Try this:

```
FOR %%i IN (*.JPG) DO ECHO ^<img src="%%i" /^> >> index.html
```

[MSDN reference](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_o.mspx?mfr=true)